# Laravel Eloquent select function cause empty relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Following is my query

```
$user = User::select(['uuid','name','about'])->with(['education','work'])->first();
```

this returns empty data for relationship `education` and `work`,
but if I remove `select` function from query I am getting data in relationship and it also returns all columns of user table which I don't want.

how can solve this problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that relationships (`with(...)`) execute an additional query to get the related results. Let's say you have one to many relationship where `users` have many `works`. `User::with('work')->find(1)` will then execute these 2 queries:

`select user where id = 1` and `select works where user_id = 1`.

So basically in order to be able to execute the second query (fetch relationship data) you need to include `id` (or whichever column you're referencing) in you select statement.

Fix:

```
$user = User::select(['uuid','name','about', 'id'])->with(['education','work'])->first();
```

Same principle in different forms applies to all relationships. For example in the inverse of `hasMany` which is `belongsTo` you would need to select the foreign key (for example `user_id`).

Answer (score 0):

One potential issue is that if you use select() with with() to eager load relationships, the with() method may not work as expected. This is because when you use select(), Laravel only retrieves the specified columns, and does not retrieve any related data. So when you try to eager load relationships with with(), Laravel may not have the data it needs to do so.

wrong::

```
 'products' => $this->product
                        ->with('files', 'categories', 'sub_categories')
                        ->select('title', 'slug', 'sku')**
                        ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(20)
```

correct ::

```
 'products' => $this->product
                ->with('files', 'categories', 'sub_categories')
                ->select('id','title', 'slug', 'sku')
                ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(20)
```